# NRF24L01 Transmission Problems between Arduino UNO and Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

I'm a beginner in using NRF24L01 tranceiver module. I tried sending a simple "Hello world" using Arduino Nano and a Arduino UNO with the use of two NRF24L01 modules. I don't get any output in the serial monitor at the receiver side. I checked the wire connection numerous times. Also checked the baud rate of both receiver code and the serial monitor are same and adddresses of the tranceiver code and the receiver code are same. Looking for a solution. Thanks in advance.

This is my tranceiver code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}
void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  delay(1000);
}
```

And this is my Receiver code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}
void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and when I tried the isChipConnected () function, it told me that one of the nrf24l01 was not connected to the SPI and I assumed that one was bad. I bought 2 nrf24l01 with antenas and they work well (mostly). ( [Here is the link to the library reference](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#ac224c55270d26dbe7b4f3492ea3056b5). Also, make sure you are using the TMRh20 version of the library, [This one](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/index.html). This is more updated and better as far as I'm aware.

Like everyone would suggest, try to solder a 10uF capacitor between GND and VCC (that module requires more power sometimes). And the last thing I tried was to use one of this socket adaptors for the 2 modules [here](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000581444984.html?src=google&src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=631-313-3945&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Gploogle_7_shopping&aff_atform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&albcp=9866812513&albag=101880764522&trgt=896505316494&crea=es4000581444984&netw=u&device=c&albpg=896505316494&albpd=es4000581444984&gclid=CjwKCAjwltH3BRB6EiwAhj0IUCfw4KSDmSKgvcsDt2Mr-7kaVs6966bjcXevAQOEUn091gvA0wYaCBoCiI0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) to use the 5v output from the arduino since it can deliver more mA and thus the module can work better.
This guide help me a little bit, I'll drop it [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=421081)
I don't see anything wrong in the code, but I'm a newbie like you so (It seems we are using the same adress in our codes)

Answer (score 1):

@Erick Navarrte @dragonflyrobotics Thank you so much for your response, I've tried each an every option you've mentioned, but for an unknown reason it didn't work out for me. Then I researched more on and found out the NRF24L01 base module.This NRF24L01 base module help you to fix 8 pin NRF24L01 series RF module without any problem. And also this module comes with 3.3V regulator and a built in capacitor and easy pin connection to connect PIC or arduino. Using NRF24L01 module and NRF24L01 base module I was successfully able to transmit data.Thanks again for taking time in answering, highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I use Chinese clone nRF24L01. It has very narrow voltage tolerance. My Arduino is also clone.
The 3.3V output voltage was 3.27. The nRF24L01 was not working.  I added a 3 terminal regulator between Arduino 5V output pin and nRF24L01. The voltage was 3.303V.
Then nRF24L01 was working normally.

```cpp
///////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(9, 10);
const byte rxAddr[6] = "00001";
void setup()
{
  radio.begin();
  radio.setRetries(15, 15);
  radio.openWritingPipe(rxAddr);
radio.stopListening();
pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  const char text[] = "Kawasaki_JP";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  
  delay(1000);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(9, 10);
const byte rxAddr[6] = "00001";
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, rxAddr);
   radio.startListening();
}
void loop()
{
  if (radio.available())
  {
    char text[32] = {0};
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////
```

library ;  https://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/github.com/TMRh20/RF24-1.4.0.zip

Comment: Nevermind, I get it.  That is weirdly specific on the voltage.  Often what happens when you add a regulator closer to the nRF24L01 (on anything else for that matter) is just that you also happen to wind up with better decoupling, or just better current capacity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the NRFLite library. It is a lot easier to use. Also make sure you have a minimum of 3.3V and 0.5A power at the radio pin. If not, it may not transmit.

Here is a TX and RX example of sending text using the NRFLite. It worked perfectly for me!

TX:

```
/*

Demonstrates sending and receiving packets of different length.

Radio    Arduino
CE    -> 9
CSN   -> 10 (Hardware SPI SS)
MOSI  -> 11 (Hardware SPI MOSI)
MISO  -> 12 (Hardware SPI MISO)
SCK   -> 13 (Hardware SPI SCK)
IRQ   -> No connection
VCC   -> No more than 3.6 volts
GND   -> GND

*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <NRFLite.h>

const static uint8_t RADIO_ID = 1;
const static uint8_t DESTINATION_RADIO_ID = 0;
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CE = 9;
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CSN = 10;

struct RadioPacket1
{
    uint8_t FromRadioId;
    uint8_t Counter;
};

struct RadioPacket2
{
    uint8_t FromRadioId;
    char Message[31];    // Note the max packet size is 32, so 31 is all we can use here.
};

NRFLite _radio;
RadioPacket1 _radioData1;
RadioPacket2 _radioData2;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    if (!_radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN))
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot communicate with radio");
        while (1); // Wait here forever.
    }

    _radioData1.FromRadioId = RADIO_ID;
    _radioData2.FromRadioId = RADIO_ID;
}

void loop()
{
    // Pick a number from 0 - 60,000.
    uint16_t randomNumber = random(60001);

    if (randomNumber > 30000)
    {
        // Send RadioPacket1.

        _radioData1.Counter++;

        Serial.print("Sending ");
        Serial.print(_radioData1.Counter);

        if (_radio.send(DESTINATION_RADIO_ID, &_radioData1, sizeof(_radioData1)))
        {
            Serial.println("...Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("...Failed");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Send RadioPacket2.

        // Create a message and assign it to the packet.
        // Strings need to be converted to a char array and note they cannot be longer
        // than 31 characters since that is the size of _radioData2.Message.
        String msg = "Hello " + String(randomNumber);
        msg.toCharArray(_radioData2.Message, msg.length() + 1);

        Serial.print("Sending '");
        Serial.print(msg);
        Serial.print("'");

        if (_radio.send(DESTINATION_RADIO_ID, &_radioData2, sizeof(_radioData2)))
        {
            Serial.println("...Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("...Failed");
        }
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

RX:

```
/*

Demonstrates sending and receiving packets of different length.

Radio    Arduino
CE    -> 9
CSN   -> 10 (Hardware SPI SS)
MOSI  -> 11 (Hardware SPI MOSI)
MISO  -> 12 (Hardware SPI MISO)
SCK   -> 13 (Hardware SPI SCK)
IRQ   -> No connection
VCC   -> No more than 3.6 volts
GND   -> GND

*/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <NRFLite.h>

const static uint8_t RADIO_ID = 0;
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CE = 9;
const static uint8_t PIN_RADIO_CSN = 10;

struct RadioPacket1
{
    uint8_t FromRadioId;
    uint8_t Counter;
};

struct RadioPacket2
{
    uint8_t FromRadioId;
    char Message[31];    // Note the max packet size is 32, so 31 is all we can use here.
};

NRFLite _radio;
RadioPacket1 _radioData1;
RadioPacket2 _radioData2;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    if (!_radio.init(RADIO_ID, PIN_RADIO_CE, PIN_RADIO_CSN))
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot communicate with radio");
        while (1); // Wait here forever.
    }
}

void loop()
{
    // 'hasData' returns the size of the packet that was received, or 0 if there is no data.
    uint8_t packetSize = _radio.hasData();

    if (packetSize == sizeof(RadioPacket1))
    {
        _radio.readData(&_radioData1);

        Serial.print("Received ");
        Serial.print(_radioData1.Counter);
        Serial.print(" from radio ");
        Serial.println(_radioData1.FromRadioId);
    }
    else if (packetSize == sizeof(RadioPacket2))
    {
        _radio.readData(&_radioData2);

        String msg = String(_radioData2.Message);

        Serial.print("Received '");
        Serial.print(msg);
        Serial.print("' from radio ");
        Serial.println(_radioData2.FromRadioId);
    }
}
```